# C++ template function recursive

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++20

I have a function that calculate determinant of a matrix.
My matrix class is like this:

```cpp
template <int Col, int Row, typename T>
class Matrix;
```

I have implemented 3 specific function for `Mat<1, 1, T>`, `Mat<2, 2, T>`, `Mat<3, 3, T>`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
float Determinant(const Matrix<1, 1, T>& mat);

template <typename T>
float Determinant(const Matrix<2, 2, T>& mat);

template <typename T>
float Determinant(const Matrix<3, 3, T>& mat);
```

And now i want to have a function that calculate determinant of matrices those have
dimension higher than 3x3. I have tried to implement it like this:

```cpp
template <int Dim, typename T>
float Determinant(const Matrix<Dim, Dim, T>& mat)
{
  float result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < Dim; ++i)
  {
    // This function return a minor matrix of `mat`
    Matrix<Dim - 1, Dim - 1, T> minor = mat.GetMinorMatrix(i, 0);
    result += (i & 1 ? -1 : 1) * mat(i, 0) * Determinant(minor); 
  }
}

// I try to use that function
Matrix<1, 1, float> mat { 1.0f };
Determinant(mat); // Error occurred here
```

But somehow my compiler keeps crashing while i try to build that code. And my IDE reports this error: `In template: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024`. That error will be disappeared when i delete the function `template <int Dim, typename T> float Determinant(const Matrix<Dim, Dim, T>& mat)`.
Why does that error happen, and how can i fix it?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa79d2ba9a68b995).  Please provide a [mcve] to help others determine what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you instantiate `Determinant` with `Dim = 0`. Your compiler will try to instantiate `Determinant<-1>`, which will then again instantiate `Determinant<-2>`, and so on. At some point you will reach the maximum 1024. A minimal reproducible example could look like:

```cpp
template <int I>
void foo() {
  foo<I - 1>();
}

int main() {
  foo<5>();
}
```

You can fix this is in different ways. The more *modern* approach would check for the final recursive call:

```
template <int I>
void foo() {
  if constexpr (I > 0) {
    foo<I - 1>();
  } else {
    // however you want to deal with I = 0
  }
}
```

Or by using template pattern matching:

```cpp
template <int I>
void foo() {
  foo<I - 1>();
}

template <>
void foo<0>() {
   // however you want to deal with I = 0
}
```